# Getting the request.https response into a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today I am doing this request to Linode API.

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'api.linode.com',
    path: '',
    port: 443,
    method: 'GET'
}

var req = https.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(d) {
        body = JSON.parse(d.toString());
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body);
    });
}).end();
```

The output is working as expected on this example.

However, I need to put the response into a variable, and not log it to console.

```
var body = '';
var req = https.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(d) {
        body = JSON.parse(d.toString());
    });
}).end();
console.log(body);
return body;
```

Running the above code, the answer is always empty, since looks like the `console.log()` function or `return` clause are not waiting for end of the request.

I resolved the problem using the `setTimeout( function() { console.log(body); }, 2000 )` function, but to be honest can't see it as an effective solution, since the timeout will be different on each request.

Other solution I tried was `while (!req.finished) {} console.log(body);`, but it is not working as expected too.

Finally, I tried to add this:

```
response.on('end', function() {
    return body;
});
```

But no success as well :(

That said, do you have any suggestions to make this function wait for request timeout before return the value of the `body` variable?

Comment: Return a promise, `then` do something when it fulfills.

Comment: @torazaburo Do you have any examples? Sorry, I got the idea, but can't see how to make it happen. Thanks!

Comment: There are about a dozen or more questions on SO on this very topic. Search for them. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call.

Comment: @torazaburo The questions I found there are to do it via AJAX, and not via Node.js using https module. However, the below answer worked as expected. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear that. The two are conceptually identical. The "modern" way to do this is with promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to put the code in a function that takes in (at least) a callback. You'll also want to buffer data from *all* `data` events since you cannot assume there will be only one. Example:

```
// you may want to add other parameters too depending on your needs of course ...
function linodeReq(cb) {
  var options = {
    hostname: 'api.linode.com',
    path: '',
    port: 443,
    method: 'GET'
  }

  https.get(options, function(response) {
    var buffer = '';
    response.on('data', function(d) {
      buffer += d;
    }).on('end', function() {
      var body;
      try {
        body = JSON.parse(buffer)
      } catch (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, body);
    }).setEncoding('utf8');
  });
}

// then use it like ...

linodeReq(function(err, result) {
  // check for `err` first ...
});
```

You should also handle the `error` events on the request (and `response`) object too, passing them to the callback if they occur. This could happen for example if the hostname couldn't be resolved or some other connection error.